# submiting form html django

Tags: html, django, database

I want to send data from my html submit for to my database(mysql).
On server side i use django(im begginer).
Can you give me example if i use 3 rows in my table "name" "email" "message".
When someone press submit i want data to be stored in DB and other users cant see them. I have read djangogirls and django tutorial 1.10 and i already made an webapp. But im stuck if i want to do something on my own.

my form in index.html

```
 <form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/myapp/">{% csrf_token %}{{form}}
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="mail" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Comm" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
{{ form.as_p }}
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>

    </form>
```

models.py

from **future** import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class bosti(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   email = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   message = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import bosti

class bosti(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email',' message')
```

myapp/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='hello.html'),

]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    ]
```

when i submit form, i get values in my url, but they arent passed in DB.

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import bosti

## Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/hello.html', {})

```
def bosti(request,
    template = 'blog/hello.html', *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       name= request.GET.get('name')
       email= request.GET.get('email')
       message= request.GET.get('message')
       Model = bosti(name = name, email = email, message = message)

       Model.save()
```

I have model bosti. When I login in db I see new table bosti_bosti.

settings.py

Installed apps:
I added myapp

DB settings, im using mysql

```
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME':'myDb',
            'USER': 'myuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypassword'


        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you configured your urls? You have to define a view for the url that will be '/myapp/'.

Comment: You dont have to use both django form and conventional html form for your requirement. Any one would be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/myapp/">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="mail" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Comm" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>

    </form>
```

models.py

```
from future import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class bosti(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   email = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   message = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import bosti

class bosti(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email',' message')
```

myapp/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='hello.html'),

]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    ]
```

when i submit form, i get values in my url, but they arent passed in DB.

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render from .models import bosti

Create your views here.

```
def index(request): return render(request, 'blog/hello.html', {})

def bosti(request,
    template = 'blog/hello.html', *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       name= request.GET.get('name')
       email= request.GET.get('email')
       message= request.GET.get('message')
       Model = bosti(name = name, email = email, message = message)

       Model.save()
```

Add this option to your Database settings:

```
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME':'myDb',
            'USER': 'myuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypassword'
            'OPTIONS': {
                'sql_mode': 'traditional',
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for example.
I tried, still cant get data in mysql.
I get my variables in url but seems they arent passed in db
i created models, but not sure what i have to do in urls(if i have to, not sure what im missing)

Comment: Edit and add your whole code then I can get a better idea, otherwise I'm just making assumptions as to what you are trying to do. The above code sends the form data to database, it uses *args instead of parameters. Add your models.py, view.py and urls.py

Comment: Can you post your view.py is well plz

Comment: Changed the form, as mentioned before, you don't need to use both Django form and conventional HTML form.

Comment: In that case i can delete forms.py?
In case i dont have proper urls configuration, can values still be passed to my db?i still cant get data.I cant get data in db and i dont know where to start looking:/

thanks for helping me

Comment: Yes you can delete it, you only need it if you are using Django forms. You can send data to database without Django forms.

Comment: I deleted forms.py, still nothing inserted in my db
when i submit form i get generated url http://mysite/name=test&email=test%40g&message=test


python manage.py migrate gives me output:  "Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'

Comment: What is your databases settings? You can find it in settings.py under DATABASES.

Comment: hey, i added settings. I use model name "bosti" in mysql db is created_bosti_bosti. Should i modfy query?

Comment: it ends with an error, if i put traditional mysql settings. I marked as answered your post. Becouse you were the only one who gave an example. Thanks for help and your time